# Yii easy deploy

Tags: deployment, yii, configuration, web-deployment

I really need help with some yii basic deploy.

We are small team (2 persons), working on a new project. We make changes online on server now (while developing) and want to start our project. 
We tried GIT, it works fine, but it is really long way to deploy and we don't need this functionallity now, because of a small size of team.

So i started to research some other ways to do it, but can't find really easy solution.

I would like to have 2 versions of Yii app on server: dev and prod, and to have ability to switch between them.

Do anyone have some kind of this realisation?

Comment: "it is really long way to deploy " I'm using git with my yii application and when a commit is done it takes less than a minute to deploy it to my webserver.
Using hooks you don't have to do anything, everything is deployed automatically after a commit is pushed to the origin git server

Comment: Agreed. Use Git, you'll like it after a bit :-)

Comment: Now i think i have no choise :-D